# Flashcache on top of luks and LVM

Tags: 14.04, flashcache

I've configured flashcache on top of luks and LVM, almost everything is working ok but I cannot mount it automatically on boot, because device is not ready yet (system hangs on boot silently). There is any simple way to run flashcache_load and mount AFTER luks and lvm startup?

Comment: Michal, have you managed to solve that problem? I'm having the same issue. I'm wondering if changing the stack would help here (flashcache caching the encrypted volume, luks on top of it)?

Comment: Yes, but install from git source not from ubuntu package and run there: make -f Makefile.dkms boot_conf
Look the comment below. After that you have to do update-initramfs

But I cannot recommend flashcache for desktop use, you will have many hangs and slowdowns, better results are with external journal for ext4 (maybe not always faster, but stable faster).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually experienced the problems with the git source, so not sure if this is the entire answer, but it still might help some people. I'm going to trust your recommendation to just not use it for desktops.

Answer (score 1):

I had to run `make -f Makefile.dkms boot_conf`

To create initramd entries.

Also you'll need to manually enable modules in grub - add below line to `/etc/default/grub.conf`:

```
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="cryptodisk luks gcry_rijndael gcry_sha1 lvm
```